# How to make a link

Tags: javascript

How to create a **link** that from the first page is weighed to the second page
For example ... how to pass from the *sign up* to the *log in* (and the remember me  make *color:red* )

---

```js
$("#sign-up-btn").click(function() {
  $("#sign-up-form").show();
  $("#log-in-form").hide();
  $("#payments-form").hide();
  $("#sign-up-btn").addClass("active");
  $("#log-in-btn").removeClass("active");
  $("#payments-btn").removeClass("active");
});

$("#log-in-btn").click(function() {
  $("#sign-up-form").hide();
  $("#log-in-form").show();
  $("#payments-form").hide();
  $("#sign-up-btn").removeClass("active");
  $("#log-in-btn").addClass("active");
  $("#payments-btn").removeClass("active");
});

$("#payments-btn").click(function() {
  $("#sign-up-form").hide();
  $("#log-in-form").hide();
  $("#payments-form").show();
  $("#sign-up-btn").removeClass("active");
  $("#log-in-btn").removeClass("active");
  $("#payments-btn").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
  background: #0D3447;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

/*btn group*/
.btn-group {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 35px auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.btn-selector {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #cccccc;
}

.btn-selector:hover,
.btn-selector:focus,
.btn-selector:active,
.btn-selector.active {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #CFCCCC;
  border-color: #adadad;
}

.btn-group .btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-group .btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group .btn:first-child:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group .btn:last-child:not(:first-child) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
/*end of btn group*/

/*form general*/
.form {
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 10px 30px 35px;
    display: block;
    width: 375px;
    background-color: #DEDCDC;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 #000;
}

.form h2 {
    color: #434740;
  font-size: 40px;
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}
.form input, .form button, .form h2 {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    font-size: 22px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"], label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #44C7A9;
}

.input-std {
    width: 95.5%;
}

.input-half {
    width: 45.9%;
    float: left;
}

.input-quarter {
    width: 21%;
    float: left;
}

.btn-submit {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 11px 19px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #cccccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-submit:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#sign-up {
    background-color: #5EB320;
}

#log-in {
    background-color: #1893A3;
}

#remember-me-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
}

#payments {
    background-color: #B33030;
}

#cvc {
    float: none;
}

#log-in-form, #payments-form {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="btn-group" id="form-selector">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-selector active" id="sign-up-btn">Sign Up</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-selector" id="log-in-btn">Log In</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-selector" id="payments-btn">Payments</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form" id="sign-up-form">
        <h2 class="form-title">Sign Up</h2>
        <input type="text" class="input-std" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" class="input-half" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" class="input-half" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input type="password" class="input-std" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="password" class="input-std" id="password-confirmation" placeholder="Password Confirmation">
        <button type="button" class="btn-submit" id="sign-up">Sign Up!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form" id="log-in-form">
        <h2 class="form-title">Log In</h2>
        <input type="text" class="input-std" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" class="input-std" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        <div id="remember-me-wrapper">
            <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
            <label for="remember-me">Remember Me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn-submit" id="log-in">Log In!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form" id="payments-form">
        <h2 class="form-title">Payments</h2>
        <input type="text" class="input-std" id="name" placeholder="Cardholder's Name">
        <input type="text" class="input-quarter" id="number" placeholder="4242" maxlength="4">
        <input type="text" class="input-quarter" id="number" placeholder="4242" maxlength="4">
        <input type="text" class="input-quarter" id="number" placeholder="4242" maxlength="4">
        <input type="text" class="input-quarter" id="number" placeholder="4242" maxlength="4">
        <input type="text" class="input-half" id="cvc" placeholder="CVC" maxlength="3">
        <input type="text" class="input-quarter" id="exp-month" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2">
        <input type="text" class="input-half" id="exp-year" placeholder="YYYY" maxlength="4">
        <button type="button" class="btn-submit" id="payments">Submit!</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5"></script>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve (though none of the downvotes were from me). You're trying to make it so that whenever you go **directly** from `'Sign Up'` to `'Log In'`, the `'Remember Me'` text is red? But when going from `'Payments'` to `'Log In'` it should be black? Could you please clarify **exactly** what you're attempting to do?

Comment: Dear.I want that in page Sign Up  there was a link for example <a href="#">link in color</a>, which conducts in page Log In and there the <remember me> color becomes  red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all your forms are in the same page but in different tabs.

What you need to do is to execute the same function executed when you click on "#log-in-btn".

```
var openLogInPage = function(){
  $("#sign-up-form").hide();
  $("#log-in-form").show();
  $("#payments-form").hide();
  $("#sign-up-btn").removeClass("active");
  $("#log-in-btn").addClass("active");
  $("#payments-btn").removeClass("active");
}
```

And then when you can redirect to that tab after subscribing your submit button to the click event with this code :

```
$("#sign-up").on("click", openLogInPage);
```

Comment: The problem is because of the jquery version you include in the file. try to use $("#sign-up").click(openLogInPage); instead.